# Jquery: loop iteration

Tags: php, jquery, iteration

Not sure if it's actually iterating once, but only one dialog is being generated. the jquery loop is aimed at a hidden input for each PHP loop iteration which counts up from one; There's two 'roomID' total.

Using alert gives me two, but it is not assigning the dialog with jquery, which in return gives me the first one. Why is this happening?

Is there a better method of doing this:

```
$('input#roomID').each(function() {
   var roomID = $('input#roomID').val();
   alert($(this).val());

            $( 'div.edit-dialog-'+roomID ).dialog({ 
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 500,
                width: 550,
                modal: true,
                position:['middle','middle'],
                draggable: true,
                //resizable: true,
                buttons: {
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                },
                    close: function() {
                        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
                    }
            });

            $( 'a.room-edit-'+roomID).click(function() {
                $( 'div.edit-dialog-'+roomID ).dialog( "open" );
            });
    });
```

I'm somewhat new to Jquery.

Comment: u can not have more than one dom element for this input#roomID selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're selecting on an id '#'.

Dom's require unique id's.

Try making it a class instead.

So instead of

```
<input id="roomID" type="text" />
```

Add a class

```
<input class="roomID" type="text" />
```

Then

```
$('input.roomID').each();
```

will select all of the inputs on the page with the class `roomID`

**EDIT**

jQuery's each function will go through the selectors matches. So say you have this HTML:

```
<input class="hello" />
<input class="hello" />
<span class="hello">text</span>
```

Then when you call each like this:

```
$('.hello').each(function(i, ele){});
```

jQuery will call the function 3 times each time the function will have `this`(or will be scoped) to the individual dom elements. It does this in the order they appear in the dom. So the first time through it will be `input` then `input` then `span`.

Each time `this` will point to the respective dom element and not a jQuery mapped element. that's why you need to do `$(this)` to access jquery's helper methods as opposed to just `this.val()`.

It also calls the function with 2 arguments, the first is the iteration number, so on the `span` case this would be 2. And the second is the element again.

Comment: Tried that, dennmat. Same result.

Comment: You'll also need to update your line `var roomID = $('input#roomID').val();` to `$(this).val()`.

Comment: OOO! That did it! That makes perfect sense too. As I'm a newbie to jquery, but understand loops well from PHP... my assumption is by using the specific 'input#roomID', it grabs the first, instead of $(this) which changes with each iteration ?

<3

Comment: Correct I'll add a brief explanation to the end of my post

Answer (score 0):

This is much better if you use [another selecto](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)r to customize the inputs.

```
 <input name="new3" />
 <input name="new2" />
 <input name="new1" />

 <script>
     $('input[name*="new"]').val('xxxxx');
 </script>
```